# How to do projects configuration with a file in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

How to change the settings of each project in Gitlab with a file?

I would like to give custom settings to projects in gitlab. I know we can do it with UI. I wonder if we can do this with a config file in Gitlab. I found an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/201794) in gitlab but it is still open. Lets think we have a 2 projects called AProject and BProject.
AProject --> approvals_required count should be 1
BProject --> approvals_required count should be 2

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box feature that fully supports your requirement, unfortunately.

However, there are a couple things you can try to apply a common "policy":

1. **Group-level settings** - some settings can be configured for a group and will be inherited to all projects under that group, for example:
   [image]
2. **Instance-level settings** - if you're running a self-hosted Gitlab instance - you will be able to apply some of the settings for all projects on instance level.
3. **API calls** - if none of the above work (or - like in your case - you need customized settings) you may need to revert to a series of API calls that are executed for every project. I have used Postman for that purpose in the past. You can then have a cron-job that will apply the settings through Gitlab API every so-often, which will also help you make sure that these settings are always set as you wanted them.